# Appending multi-dimensional arrays of different shapes in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Arrays `C1` and `C2` have shapes `(1, 2, 2)` and `(1, 1, 2)` respectively. I want to append these arrays into a new array `C3`. But I am getting an error. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

arC1 = []
arC2 = []

C1=np.array([[[0, 1],[0,2]]])
arC1.append(C1)
C2=np.array([[[1,1]]])
C2.shape
arC2.append(C2)

C3=np.append(C1,C2,axis=0)
```

The error is

```
 <module>
    C3=np.append(C1,C2,axis=0)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append

  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

The desired output is

```
C3[0]=np.array([[[0, 1], [0, 2]]])
C3[1]=np.array([[2,3]])
```

Comment: please provide the expected output as array directly

Comment: you can only `concatenate` (1,2,2) and (1,1,2) on axis 1, making a (1,3,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C1 = np.array([[[0, 1],[0,2]]])
print(C1.shape)  # (1, 2, 2)
C2 = np.array([[[1,1]]])
print(C2.shape)  # (1, 1, 2)
```

If you run

```
C3 = np.append(C1,C2,axis=1)
print(C2.shape)  # (1, 3, 2)
```

It means like this. (1, **2**, 2) + (1, **1**, 2) = (1, **3**, 2)

If you run

```
C3 = np.append(C1,C2,axis=0)
```

It means like this. (**1**, 2, 2) + (**1**, 1, 2) = (**2**, **??**, 2)

Since numpy is a matrix, it can't be added because the lower dimensions are different.

---

Simply, when you set **axis** parameter value at **append function** for append two arrays, the values of all dimensions shall be the same except for the values of the dimensions corresponding to the axis

#### **example 1**

```
C1 = np.array([[[[[0, 1]]],[[[0, 2]]], [[[0, 2]]]]])
C2 = np.array([[[[[1]]],[[[2]]], [[[3]]]]])
C3 = np.append(C1, C2, axis=4)
```

and if the dimensions are as follows,

```
(1, 3, 1, 1, 2)  # C1
(1, 3, 1, 1, 1)  # C2

-->
(1, 3, 1, 1, 3)  # C3
```

Only axis 4 dimmension is different so you can do **np.append(C1, C2, axis=4)**

#### **example 2**

```
C1 = np.array([[[[[0, 1]]],[[[0, 2]]], [[[0, 2]]]]])
C2 = np.array([[[[[1, 1]]],[[[2, 2]]], [[[3, 3]]]], [[[[1, 1]]],[[[2, 2]]], [[[3, 3]]]]])
C3 = np.append(C1, C2, axis=0)
```

and if the dimensions are as follows,

```
(1, 3, 1, 1, 2)  # C1
(2, 3, 1, 1, 2)  # C2

-->
(3, 3, 1, 1, 2)  # C3
```

Only axis 0 dimmension is different so you can do **np.append(C1, C2, axis=0)**

#### **example 3**

```
C1 = np.array([[[[[0, 1]]],[[[0, 2]]], [[[0, 2]]]]])
C2 = np.array([[[[[1]]],[[[2]]], [[[3]]]], [[[[1]]],[[[2]]], [[[3]]]]])
```

and if the dimensions are as follows,

```
(1, 3, 1, 1, 2)  # C1
(2, 3, 1, 1, 1)  # C2

-->
ERROR
```

Except for the Axis value you specify, at least one dimension is more different. So it's impossible to set **axis** parameter with these arrays.